# React Js, state is updating when console loggin but UI is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i have a object which is storing 3 input states . I have a clear all button which will clear all the states and update the ui with empty values as a normal clear should work . The problem here is when i click it's actually udating and setttin input values to empty string . But it's not updating the UI

**Here is the state with values:**
[image]

**Here is the state when i clear**

[image]
[image]

**UI is still not changing**

[image]

**Excepted behaviour: Update the Ui with the empty values**

Here is the code below

```js
const initSelects = (fields) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    fields.map(({ name, defaultValue }) => [name, defaultValue ?? ''])
  );
};

const Sorter = ({ menuItemsValue, setSortData, activeSort }: SortProps) => {
  const fields: SorterProps[] = [
    {
      name: 'sorterParam1',
      title: 'Sort by',
      optional: true,
      defaultValue: activeSort?.field,
      options: [],
    },
    {
      name: 'sorterParam2',
      title: 'Then by',
      optional: true,
      options: [],
    },
    {
      name: 'sorterParam3',
      title: 'Then by',
      optional: true,
      options: [],
    },
  ];

  const [select, setSelect] = useState<any>(() => initSelects(fields));

  const fieldsWithOptions = useMemo(() => {
    const taken = new Set();
    return fields.map((field, index) => {
      // This will work just for this case
      const filteredOptions = menuItemsValue.filter(
        (item) =>
          item.field !== select[`sorterParam${index}`] && // recieve_ts !==
          item.field !== select[`sorterParam${index - 1}`]
      );

      console.log(filteredOptions);

      const withOptions = {
        ...field,
        options: filteredOptions,
      };

      // only track non-empty values
      if (select[field.name]) {
        // exclude the current field selection
        taken.add(select[field.name]);
      }
      return withOptions;
    });
  }, [fields, menuItemsValue, select]);

  const handleSelectChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setSelect({ ...select, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleClearAllInputs = () => {
    setSelect({
      sorterParam1: '',
      sorterParam2: null,
      sorterParam3: null,
    });

    const closeIt = () => {
      const muiEl = document.querySelector('.MuiPaper-root') as any;
      muiEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    };

    setTimeout('closeIt', 3000);

    closeIt();
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      label="Advanced Sorting"
      className={styles.sorter__inputs}
      id="sorter-parameter-1"
      variant="standard"
    >
      {fieldsWithOptions.map((option, index) => {
        return (
          <SorterField
            key={option.name}
            menuItemsValue={option.options}
            name={option.name}
            option={option}
            count={fields.length}
            handleChange={handleSelectChange}
            index={index + 1} // setData={setData}
            activeSort={activeSort}
            setSortData={setSortData}
          />
        );
      })}
      <div className={styles.sorter__inputControllers}>
        <Button
          className={styles.sorter__clearAllInput}
          onClick={handleClearAllInputs}
        >
          Clear All
        </Button>
      </div>
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default Sorter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum reproducible example.

Comment: I just did that now , thank you for reminding me !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should pass as prop the selected value to your `SorterField` and display it as the value

```
 <SorterField
     key={option.name}
     menuItemsValue={option.options}
     name={option.name}
     selectedOption={select[option.name]}
     option={option}
     count={fields.length}
     handleChange={handleSelectChange}
     index={index + 1} // setData={setData}
     activeSort={activeSort}
     setSortData={setSortData}
/>
```